# Finding subsets inside a cell array

Tags: matlab

Consider a cell array, `I`, where

```
I = { [i_1 ; i_2 ; .... ; i_n] [i_1,i_2 ; i_1,i_3; ...; i_n,i_n-1 ].. [ % all NCi combinations] ...}
```

Now, I want to find the number of times each row of each cell appears as a subset of another row of a different cell.

For example, I want to find the number of times `i_1`, `i_2` appear together in the same row in the whole cell array.

```
I = {[1;2;3] [(1,2);(2,3);(1,3)] [1,2,3]}
```

`ans = 2`. (once in the 1st row of the 2nd cell and once in the only row of the 3rd cell).

I have been trying different things with this member but I'm just not able to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: I hadn't framed the question properly. I am working on posting it with more relevance to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that makes use of the "rows" argument of `ismember` (note that `[1 2]` will be found in `[1 2 3]` with this approach).

```
I = {[1;2;3],[1,2;2,3;1,3],[1,2,3]};
bait = [1 2];
baitCols = size(bait,2);

%# identify cells with sufficient columns for comparison
goodIdx = cellfun(@(x)size(x,2) >= baitCols,I);

%# count all occurrences
count = sum(cellfun(@(x)sum(ismember(x(:,1:baitCols),bait,'rows')),I(goodIdx)));
```

Comment: For me it is not working: `Inputs A and B must be matrices with the same number of columns in
the 'rows' case.`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. 
However, it doesn't seem to work properly. For example:
If I make 
     I = {[1;2;3;4], [1,2;2,3;1,3;1,4;2,4;3,4], [1,2,3;2,3,4;1,2;4] [1,2,3,4]} 

count should be 4 but it returns only 3.

Comment: In essence, it counts [1,2] only once for each cell even if it appears  multiple times. 
EG: I={ [1,2] ,[1,2;1,2;1,2;1,2;1,2], [1,2,3;1,2,3] }
Count = 3 where as it should be 8.

Comment: @Nishanth: Thanks. I have simplified your edits a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty loop:

```
 I = {[1;2;3],[1,2;2,3;1,3],[1,2,3]};
 i_1 = 1;
 i_2 = 2;

 count = 0;
 for ii=1:numel(I),
     for jj=1:size(I{ii},1)
         if any(I{ii}(jj,:)==i_1) && any(I{ii}(jj,:)==i_2)
             count = count+1;
         end
     end
 end
```